How to access GIT_COMMIT in a custom Jenkins plugin?
I'm developing a custom Jenkins plugin and need to access the GIT_COMMIT environment variable.
In Jenkins freestyle jobs, this variable is automatically available, but I'm struggling to access it within my plugin when running pipelines.
I've tried using build.getEnvironment() to retrieve the environment variables, but GIT_COMMIT does not seem to be populated. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:
import hudson.model.Run;
import hudson.EnvVars;

public class MyCustomPlugin {
    public void getGitCommit(Run<?, ?> build) {
        try {
            // Get the environment variables for the build
            EnvVars envVars = build.getEnvironment(null);
            
            // Retrieve the GIT_COMMIT variable
            String gitCommit = envVars.get("GIT_COMMIT");
            
            if (gitCommit != null) {
                System.out.println("GIT_COMMIT: " + gitCommit);
            } else {
                System.out.println("GIT_COMMIT not found in the environment.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

However, when I run the plugin, GIT_COMMIT is always null.
How can I reliably access the GIT_COMMIT for a pipeline build in my plugin?
Is there an alternative approach I should use, such as accessing the SCM directly?
I’m open to either retrieving it from the environment or through the SCM, but I'm not sure which is the best approach in the context of a pipeline.

I would use SCM plugin to get build revision and commit information.
I would try somthing like this :
import hudson.model.Run;
import hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM;
import hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData;
import hudson.plugins.git.Branch;
import hudson.scm.SCM;

public class MyCustomPlugin {
    public void getGitCommitAndBranch(Run<?, ?> build) {
        SCM scm = build.getParent().getTypicalSCM();  // Fetching the SCM details from the job

        if (scm instanceof GitSCM) {
            GitSCM gitScm = (GitSCM) scm;
            BuildData buildData = gitScm.getBuildData(build);
            
            if (buildData != null && buildData.getLastBuiltRevision() != null) {
                String gitCommit = buildData.getLastBuiltRevision().getSha1String();
                List<Branch> branches = buildData.getLastBuiltRevision().getBranches();
                
                if (!branches.isEmpty()) {
                    String branchName = branches.get(0).getName();
                    System.out.println("Last commit hash: " + gitCommit);
                    System.out.println("Branch: " + branchName);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Commit available, but no branch information found.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("This job does not use Git SCM.");
        }
    }
}

